# Javascript: extract what's after the searched word in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains the following :

```
a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)
```

and i want to search for `Test` and get what it follows after it.

i tried `string.includes("Test")` but it only returns true or false

Comment: please share the complete string

Comment: Just use `indexof` instead of `includes` and if > -1 then use that + length of string to `substr` anything after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to `split()` the Sting on the text you want and the result[1] will be the text after the splitting string.

so...

```
var s = 'a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)';
var splitText = 'Test'
var result = s.split(splitText)[1];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @brxnzaz `split` should work, as demonstrated above.  The thing to keep in mind is when your test pattern (e.g., `Test`) is not found in the string. In the example above, `s.split()[1]` will be `undefined`.  As long as you're aware and test for it many of the methods below will work and your decision to use one over another should come to preference and readability.  If performance is a concern, for instance if you're doing this over 1M rows, you should pursue what method works best in that case.  Good luck

Answer (score 6):

You could match the wanted word and take all characters after.

```js
var string = 'a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)',
    part = string.match(/Test(.*$)/)[1];
    
console.log(part);
```

If the string is likely not to match, you could add  a default array for a `null` value and get `undefied` instead of a nonmatched part.

```js
var string = 'a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)',
    part = (string.match(/TestX(.*$)/) || [])[1];
    
console.log(part);
```

Comment: I respect your reputation, but I have to mention that `match` is not my preferred method as it will inevitably require error handling (more code) if the pattern is not in the string.  For instance, remove the `e` from `Test` in the string to see what happens.  As such, I often find that `RegExp.test()` to be a simpler and robust solution.  Still.. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a capture group inside a regular expression to capture everything after the matched pattern (your string).  Below tests if you found it, if you did the value will be stored in the `$1` of the `RegExp` object.

```js
const str = 'a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)'

if ( /Test(.*)$/.test(str) )
  console.log(RegExp.$1)
```

Here is another way to functionalize the above:

```js
const text = 'a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)'
console.log( trailing(text, 'Test') )


  
  
function trailing(str, pattern){
  const re = new RegExp(`${pattern}(.*)$`)
  if ( re.test(str) )
    return RegExp.$1.toString()
  return '' // false and default condition
}
```

Comment: it's a great one, but once i add \n\n after the test, it returns nothing. i wanted something that will work in every case. and split did the job

Comment: @brxnzaz there are a couple things you can do with that. A newline character changes how regex operates, since the text is generally put into lines.  You have several options.  (1) You can put the regex into single line mode using the `s` flag: `/Test(.*)$/s.test(str)` -- notice the "s" after the last "/", (2) the `.` wildcard doesn't capture newlines, so you can adjust the pattern match to also look for them: `/Test((.|\s)*)$/.test(str)` -- notice no trailing "s"; (3) you could filter out the newlines before matching.  Any of these should work

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to get index of the element that you searched: [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- After that you can get extracted text that includes your keyword using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

I have also created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/woo68x7rvl) that helps you to understand.

```
const getAfterText = (allText, keyword) => {
  return allText.slice(allText.indexOf(keyword));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of word and then get the substring.

```js
let str = 'a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)',
    word = 'Test',
    substring = '';
if(str.indexOf(word) > -1) {
    substring = str.substr(str.indexOf(word) + word.length);
}
console.log(substring);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `lastIndexOf` and `substr` is a easy fit for your case:

```js
let text = 'a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)'
let position = text.lastIndexOf('Test: ')
let result = position > -1 ? text.substr(position + 6) : ''
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi @brk, `position` is a `Number` containing the index of the last occurrence of the searched sentence (`'Test: '`), not the sentence itself. Sure we could create one more variable to put the searched sentence inside and use that. Since the OP clearly stated that `'Test: '` is the only thing he wants to search, I thought that it wound't be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way to do it:

```
const yourString = "a test here as well .... Test: 1- (link) 2- (link)";
const searchTerm = "Test";
const result = yourString.split(searchTerm).at(1);
```