# Filter out variables from HTML for GTM after purchase

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to filter out the Name, Street, Postal code and City from this part of HTML?

```
<div class="xlwcty_Mview">
    <p>
        John Doe<br>
        Townstreet 13<br>
        1234AB Bigcity
    </p>
</div>
```

I know how I can filter out certain pieces of "content"based on class, ID or something else (unique), but I need to seperate Name, Street Postal code and City from eachother.

At first I started out in GTM by setting up a Variable with DOM-element and then "class is equal to xlwcty_Mview". But it gave me the whole block of text.
I then had the idea of a piece of Javascript that would search for a with the class "xlwcty_Mview", then start after the "`<p>`" and stop at the first `<br>`. A second piece of code with start at the first `<br>` and stop at the second `<br>`. The third piece would start at the second `<br>` and stop at the first `[space]`. The last part would start at the last `[space]` and end at the last `<br>`.

But seeind as I am a very novice with Javascript I haven't been able to find seomthing that would do the trick. I am not capable of writing anything like this myself. And I'm not even sure if my theory would be the most logical approach?

I tried to edit: [Extract the text out of HTML string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899298/extract-the-text-out-of-html-string-using-javascript) but I wasn't succesful. Eventually I found this topic: [Javascript: extract what's after the searched word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143182/javascript-extract-whats-after-the-searched-word-in-a-string) and I tried to see if I could edit it to do the above, but I only got errors which I couldn't understand.

I have a working variable in GTM which returns: "John Doe Townstreet 13 1234AB Bigcity" (so no HTML I'm afraid).

Edit:
I have been succesful in finding a piece of Woocommerce code that allows me to change the HTML format a bit. As a test I have added a second column that looks like:

```
<div class="order-data-thank-you">
<ul>
<li class="customer-name">John Doe</li>
<li class="customer-address">Townstreet 13<br>1234AB Bigcity</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This means that extracting the name is easy, but the address, postal code and city is still a bit out-of-my-league.

Comment: Probably easiest if you get the `innerText` of the `. xlwcty_Mview` element, and then just split that at the line breaks ...? https://jsfiddle.net/6zgdv2nu/ (Postal code and city contained in the last element, you will then still have to split. Whether you can just do that at the first space, depends on where your addresses are "from" - for UK post codes for example, that probably would not work.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of this option. I kinda assumed that `<br>` was not the same as a linebreak `/n`.
In this case, Postal codes would always be formatted as "1234AB" but unfortunately it can also be "1234 AB" (with a space).
Thank you for the jsfiddle, but I'm afraid I don't know how to split these items up. In the end these would need be put in their own variable.
BTW I have made an edit to my post.